# How do I detect a non-programmatic disconnection from the MCSession of the current device?

Tags: ios, swift, multipeer-connectivity

To avoid being an XY problem, I will explain the situation first.

I am developing a game in which multiple devices can connect with each other to have a multiplayer game. I am using Multipeer Connectivity for this. The game supports 2-4 players.

Now I need to handle the case of a player disconnecting from all the other players. The game should still continue when a player disconnects, unless there is only one player left. However, I want an alert to be displayed to all the still-connected players saying "XXX has disconnected" and "kills" the player who disconnected, and another alert to the disconnected player saying that "You disconnected" and dismissing the Game View Controller.

The player can disconnect in the following ways:

- pressing the quit button
- turning off the screen (this makes the app goes into background which stops all Mutipeer Connectivity apparently)
- Turning on Airplane mode
- Getting too far away from the others

Everything apart from the first way cannot be controlled programmatically. I can currently implement the first one like this:

When the user presses the quit button, just after `session.disconnect()` is called, I can show the message "You disconnected". In `sessionPeerDidChangeState` delegate method, I can detect that a player has disconnected and I can show "XXX disconnected" alert there.

However, I cannot figure out how to handle the other cases. During my own testing, I discovered that if the user turns their screen off, the `sessionPeerDidChangeState` delegate method is not even called. Even if it is called, how am I supposed to figure out whether the device is the one disconnected or not? I need to know this to show an appropriate message and decide whether or not to "kill" the player who disconnected.

I understand that this is not possible with a session consisting of 2 peers, since it is impossible to determine "who disconnect from whom". The game can't continue with only 1 player anyway, so I'm just going to show "All other players have left" alert and dismiss the Game View Controller if I see that `self.session.connectedPeers` is empty. I'm only concerned about the case where there are 3 players and 1 of them left. I should be able to know which player it is that disconnected, but I don't know how.

Comment: for the second one can't you just use `applicationDidEnterBackground` ? For checking the airplane mode see this thread here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804398/detect-airplane-mode-on-ios and make use of the delegates to check if they turned it off or on. As for getting too far away from others do you mean physically? or in the game? if it's the former then i'm not too sure aside from constantly listening to other peoples location

Comment: @TNguyen I know that exists but the list of ways to disconnect is not limited to what I have in the question. I don't think I can possibly handle all cases. I am looking for a way to detect a disconnection, no matter the reason.

Comment: Can you maybe let us know how you connect the players, for example if you have 3 players, does one player act as `Browser (MCNearbyServiceBrowser)` and others as `Advertisers (MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser)`? Or do you do it some other way

Comment: @Ladislav Yes that's exactly how I connect the players, but does this matter? After the game starts, I throw away all the advertisers and browsers because you can't join an ongoing game.

Comment: When I did my testing if one of the connected peers turns on Airplane mode, I always got a delegate call that peer has disconnected, although it takes some time - usually like 5-8 seconds after I put on the airplane mode...

Comment: @Ladislav Yes, airplane mode will cause the delegate method to be called. I just need to figure out how to detect whether the current device is the one who disconnected or not.

Comment: So if you have 3 players and one disconnects because of Airplane mode for example, 2 devices will see that one peer disconnected, but the one device that went to Airplane mode will see 2 devices disconnected. So device with airplane mode will have 0 connected peers and other 2 devices will still have 1 connected peer since they are still connected to each other...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156990/discussion-between-sweeper-and-ladislav).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say you have 3 peers connected (peer 1, peer 2 and peer 3). Lets say peer 3 turns on Airplane mode. Peer 1 and peer 2 would get a delegate call `sessionPeerDidChangeState` that peer 3 has disconnected. But peers 1 and 2 still have connection between themselves (so both will have `self.session.connectedPeers == 1`).

On the other hand peer 3 will see that both peer 1 and peer 2 disconnected one after another and `self.session.connectedPeers == 0` and thus peer 3 can assume it was the one who lost the connection.

And as is noted in the question if home button is pressed than you can disconnect from the session in `applicationDidEnterBackground`.